# How do I run a function after a function is done Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to do this for a long time my problem is that I trying to make I run a function and it is finished (obviously) I want to make it run another function.I am using Swift SpriteKit
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you know how to call a function, right? If so, what exactly is the problem? Post some example code and more context.

Answer (score 0):

Use a completion block using a closure. This is the syntax:

```
{(parameters) -> (return type) in expression statements}
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/9/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift). The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to run 2 Code Blocks one after another, then simply make
>   two RunBlock Functions and let them Run in A Seqence!

```
 var func1 = SKAction.runBlock({
         var sprite1 = SKSpriteNode()
         sprite..... // Set Propertys of sprite1
         self.addChild(sprite1)

    })
    var func2 = SKAction.runBlock({
         var sprite2 = SKSpriteNode()
         sprite..... // Set Propertys of srite2
         self.addChild(sprite2)

    })

    var seq = SKAction.seqence([func1, func2])

    self.runAction(seq)
```